# Can I use DataAnnotations with Viewmodel classes in WPF like MVC

Tags: wpf, validation, automapper, data-annotations

In my solution I have WPF project, and WCF project that works with a database.i use `AutoMapper` to map objects.

My question is: can I use DataAnnotations with my viewmodel classes, and map them to objects received from the WCF service project? like i do in Asp.net MVC project

i want use DataAnnotations for validation

like that

```
 public class MContact
 {
      [Required(ErrorMessage = " Name is required.")]
      [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No more than 50 characters")]
      [Display(Name = "Name")]
      public string Name { get; set; }


      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
      [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "No more than 50 characters")]
      [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Valid email required e.g. abc@xyz.com")]
      public string Email { get; set; }


      [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
      [Required]
      [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$",
            ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
      public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

      public string Address { get; set; }
      [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$",
    ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
      public string Mobil { get; set; }

 }
```

and this is my xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="WPFClient.AddNewContact"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AddNewContact" Height="342" Width="432" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WPFClient.PhoneBookServiceReference" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Add Contact">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,21,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="168" Width="357">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="194" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="64*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Name:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,6" Name="nameTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />

            <Label Content="Email:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,6" Name="emailTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />

            <Label Content="Phone Number:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,6" Name="phoneNumberTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />

            <Label Content="Mobil:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,6" Name="mobilTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" />


            <Label Content="Address:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBox  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,6" Name="addressTextBox"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="151" />

        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
         <Button Content="Add" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,217,0,0" Name="btnAdd" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,217,0,0" Name="btnCancel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: What would you map the attributes to? What does the destination type look like?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker the code above is my destination type

Comment: Do you want to know if Automapper can "map" an MContact instance directly to your WPF UI?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to implement IDataErrorInfo interface manually.

From [sharing-validation-code-between-a-wpf-client-a-wcf-service-and-entity-framework-4-1-using-data-annotations](http://blogs.infosupport.com/sharing-validation-code-between-a-wpf-client-a-wcf-service-and-entity-framework-4-1-using-data-annotations/) :

> You have to understand that in WPF, unlike in Silverlight, the data annotations aren’t automatically read by the components (DataGrid). You’ll have to implement the IDataErrorInfo interface and validate manually using the data annotations.